# JTextField is blanking out my JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtextfield

I am attempting to learn more about creating more dynamic GUI's. I am hoping to add different panels with different content and as you press buttons on one main panel, it changes the adjacent panels. I have added two panels and some buttons and when I test the program, it displays correctly. The problem is when I add a `JTextField` (or `JTextArea`) the panels are blank and there are no buttons. The strange thing is I haven't added the `JTextField` to either panel. I have only created a global variable. If I comment it out, the program runs correctly. Am I missing something very simple?

Here is the `gameWindow` class that has the `JTextField`

```
package rpgcreator;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class gameWindow extends JPanel {
    JPanel startWindowPanel;
    JPanel settingsPanel;
    JPanel characterPanel;
    JPanel scenarioPanel;
    JPanel mapPanel;

    JButton CharacterButton = new JButton("Create your character");
    JButton StoryButton = new JButton("Choose your Story line");
    JButton MapButton = new JButton("Choose your World");

    //JTextField nameField = new JTextField(15); //comment or uncomment to see issue

    public gameWindow() {

        setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2,5,0));

        startWindowPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        settingsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));

        startWindowPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        settingsPanel.setBackground(Color.black);

        startWindowPanel.add(MapButton);
        startWindowPanel.add(StoryButton);
        startWindowPanel.add(CharacterButton);

        add(startWindowPanel);
        add(settingsPanel);
    }

}
```

Here is main

```
package rpgcreator;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class RPGCreator extends JFrame{

private static void mainWindow(){
    RPGCreator mainwindow = new RPGCreator();
    mainwindow.setSize(1200, 800); 
    mainwindow.setResizable(false);
    mainwindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
    mainwindow.setTitle("RPG Creator"); 
    mainwindow.setVisible(true);
    mainwindow.add(new gameWindow());
    mainwindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    mainWindow();
}

}
```

Comment: Wait, where exactly do you add the textfield/textarea? I see the commented out textfield, but I don't see where you actually add it.

Comment: I haven't added the JtextField to any panels. I only created the variable and it blanks out my panels if I leave it un-commented. This is why I am stuck and can't seem to figure out whats going on.

Comment: Try moving the visibility code, see my answer. See if that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setVisible` should go at the end. You're currently setting visible to true, and then adding a panel.

```
mainwindow.setVisible(true);
mainwindow.add(new gameWindow());
```

Put `setVisible` at the end after `setDeaultCLoseOperation`

Comment: +1 The code works for me but  what you say is a big truth, and here is where the problem relies i think

Comment: Ah, so the frame is visible when the components are added to it. A call to `validate()` will also fix the problem, hence why my suggestion to use `pack()` also works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why it does it, maybe someone else can explain.

What I do know, is I usually call `pack()` which seems to make your problem go away.

```
private static void mainWindow(){
    final RPGCreator mainwindow = new RPGCreator();
    mainwindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1200, 800));
    mainwindow.setResizable(false);
    mainwindow.setTitle("RPG Creator");
    mainwindow.setVisible(true);
    mainwindow.add(new gameWindow());
    mainwindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainwindow.pack(); //This usually goes after you've added all of your components
    mainwindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

Some notes:

1. I had to change to `mainwindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1200, 800));` to avoid the frame looking squashed. Although I would usually let the layout manager deal with the sizes of things.
2. Call `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` after you call `pack()` so that it has the desired effect. Again not sure why, but I've learnt that through some hardship.

Comment: Thank you Dan that worked. I am baffled as to what caused that issue

Comment: See @peeskillet's answer. I'd probably pick his as the chosen answer too. It gets to the root of the problem. Basically, the order of the method calls matters. You made your JFrame visible before you added the components, so Swing gets a bit confused. Calling `pack()` forces the JFrame to re-render, which gets it back into line. Ultimately, you could just change the order of your method calls.